# C++ "multiple types in one declaration" error

Tags: c++

Why do I get the `"multiple types in one declaration"` error when I compile my C++ program?

Comment: Please show the code in question

Comment: Because you have multiple types in one declaration. If you want good help, we need code.

Comment: Show not only the code, but tell which compiler.

Comment: For anyone reading this, I encountered this error when missing the semicolon `;` after an `enum class` declaration.

Comment: In my case I was compiling a program with g++ which was supposed to be compiled by gcc.(becase I have to use C++ class in a large C program, I'm working on it..) and there was a variable name 'class' which is a keyword in C++. I had another similar instance with variable 'new'. You know 'int class;' looks like two consecuitve types with no variable name!

Comment: For me it was a method defined in the .h file but not in the .cpp file.

Comment: I love this forum... found the root cause of the issue here. Guess what: a missing semicolon after an enum declaration... so for everybody running into this issue. Have a look at the instruction directly before (in my case they were in a separate header file)

Answer (score 142):

You probably have code that's the equivalent of

```
int float x;
```

probably

```
class Foo { } float x;
```

or in it's more common form (note the missing semicolon after closing curly bracket)

```
class Foo {
  //
}

float x;
```

Comment: For me, I forgot to add a semicolon after declaring a struct.

Comment: I explain the missing semicolon case more [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762300/4561887). It just happened to me minutes ago.

Answer (score 59):

Don't forget to check for `;` after enum declarations, too.

Comment: This got me while porting code from C# to C++. In C# the semicolon is optional.

Comment: This is the exact problem that made me search for this question.

Comment: @qsp And in this case the error message is not obvious, that's why I put the answer ;) Happy to hear it is still useful.

Comment: I go into more detail on this one [in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69762300/4561887).

Comment: Thank you. Dear god, way to make the message as unhelpful as possible. Feels like compiler writers are no longer human and lack the ability to speak human languages.

Answer (score 31):

I had the same problem. Sometimes the error line does not show the correct place. Go through all new-created/modified classes and see if you forget ";" in the end of class defifnition.

Comment: this should be the suggested answer cos I got the same problem only to see that a list of new headers I had included had a missing ";"

Comment: others have also mentioned ';' issue especially @Msalters with example also. why is none marked as answer?

Answer (score 14):

You must have declared twice the same variable in some class or two classes with the same name. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600707/multiple-types-in-one-declaration-but-no-missing) on Stack Overflow, for example.

You could be also missing a `;` or you could have a class definition with broken syntax ...

If you can show us some code, that would be better!

Comment: Good guess. miss a ; after a } of a class definition.

Answer (score 9):

My guess is you're missing a closing brace somewhere in a class definition, or a semicolon after it.

Answer (score 8):

Also, you may have forgotten a semicolon in a forward declaration:

```
class Foo // <-- forgot semicolon

class Bar {
  ...
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a yet another scenario that can pop up the same error

```
struct Field
{   // <------ Forget this curly brace
    enum FieldEnum
    {
        FIRSTNAME,
        MIDDLENAME,
        LASTNAME,
        UNKNOWN
    };
};
```

Answer (score 4):

### C or C++ error: "multiple types in one declaration": Further explanation for the case where you simply forgot the semicolon (`;`) at the end of a *class*, *enum*, or *struct* definition

Imagine you have the following code:

```cpp
enum class ErrorType {
    MY_ERROR_1 = 0,
    MY_ERROR_2,
    MY_ERROR_3,
    /// Not a valid value; this is the number of enums
    _COUNT,
}  // <====== MISSING SEMICOLON (;)!

class MyClass {
public:
    // some stuff
private:
    // some stuff
};
```

Since I forgot the semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `enum class` definition, after the curly brace, it *looks like* I am defining the entire `class MyClass` *inside of* the `enum class ErrorType`, so I get the error!:

> ```
> ../my_header.h:43:1: error: multiple types in one declaration
>    43 | };
>       | ^
> ```

...where line 43 in my case is at the end of the `class MyClass` definition.

**SOLUTION**: add the missing semicolon (`;`) at the end of the `enum` definition, [as stated by @eguaio here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23271049/4561887) and [@MSalters here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1754719/4561887).

Answer (score 2):

Agree with the above. Also, if you see this, preprocess the app and look at the .i
Search for the "offending" name. Then look back up. You'll often see the "}" w/o ";" on a class in the first non-with space above. Finding the problem is often harder than knowing what it is.

Comment: On my screen right now, "above" your answer is the question. Suggest you [edit] to be more clear about which of the 7 other answers this is an addition to!